# SQL Network Name owned by Available Storage OwnerGroup in Server 2012 FCI

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, clustering, failover

I did a simple `get-clusterresource` and noticed the '`owner group`' is '`available storage`'.  Not `SQL Server (instance)`for the `SQL Server Network Name (instance)`.  I want to fix this ASAP but I'm having a hard time finding out how to move a owner group only.

Or actually from what I can tell the SQL Network Name (instance) isnt even supposed to be a 'network name'.  It's a instance.  I think this is a extra line I don't need and should remove this:

```
SQL IP Address 1 (clsnwname... Online                        SQL Server (I1)             IP Address
SQL IP Address 1 (clsnwname2... Online                        SQL Server (I2)              IP Address
SQL Network Name (clsnwname... Online                        SQL Server (I1)             Network Name
SQL Network Name (clsnwname2... Online                        SQL Server (I2)              Network Name
SQL Network Name (I1)       Failed                        Available Storage             Network Name
SQL Server (I2)              Online                        SQL Server (I2)              SQL Server
SQL Server (I1)             Online                        SQL Server (I1)             SQL Server
SQL Server Agent (I2)        Online                        SQL Server (I2)              SQL Server Agent
SQL Server Agent (I1)       Online                        SQL Server (I1)             SQL Server Agent
```

I was testing a new server that will be released at some point and noticed the Windows Updates were not installing SQL updates.  It stated it cannot update because the IP is offline.

I tested failover repeatedly and it always has worked, and continues to work as shown in the GUI with no issues and IP is up.  Replication and all connections are working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a rogue client access point was added or someone manually moved/changed something.

Your two instances are as such:

```
SQL Server (I2)              Online                        SQL Server (I2)
SQL Server (I1)             Online                        SQL Server (I1)
```

They have corresponding network names in the proper groups:

```
SQL Network Name (clsnwname... Online                        SQL Server (I1)
SQL Network Name (clsnwname2... Online                        SQL Server (I2)
```

Each client access point also has at least one online IP:

```
SQL IP Address 1 (clsnwname... Online                        SQL Server (I1)
SQL IP Address 1 (clsnwname2... Online                        SQL Server (I2)
```

The outlier (failed) client access point:

```
SQL Network Name (I1)       Failed                        Available Storage
```

Which you've stated isn't part of any of the SQL Resource Groups, isn't online (failed) doesn't have an IP associated with it (as far as we can tell from your output).

This leads me to believe:

1. Someone attempted to make this and didn't know what they were doing
2. Incorrect automated setup was run (with DSC, powershell, or other tooling [chef, puppet,etc])
3. Testing was done and not cleaned up properly

I doubt it was malicious. In any event, check out the dependency report - which I'm guessing will be blank. If it is, feel free to remove it and the associated computer object in AD. If it isn't blank, update the post with more information please.